# Content of MS-DOS to a file

Tags: logging, jenkins, command-prompt

I run  a Jenkins job, in which I am supposed to save all the data that is present in the Command Prompt window of the test machine(including the functions that the jenkins job would call internally). Is there a possibility to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can see output in Jenkins **Console output**

Comment: But in console output, I can't see the complete log. A few of them are missing.